# Efficient way to check if dictionary key exists and has value

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

Let's say there's a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {"key1": "value1", "key2": {"key3": "value3"}}
```

The dictionary may or may not contain `key2`, also `key2` might be empty. So in order To get `value3`, I would need to check if `key2` and its value exist with non-null values, same applies for `key3`.

Now the obvious stupid solution would be like this:

```
if 'key2' in d:
    if d['key2']:
        if 'key3' in d['key2']:
            value = d['key2']['key3']
```

Now, I wonder if there's  a simpler solution so I don't have to write 3 `if`s in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to expect the failure and catch it:

```
try:
    value = d['key2']['key3']
except (KeyError, TypeError):
    pass
```

(don't call your variable the name of the type, it's a bad practice, I've renamed it `d`)

The `KeyError` catches a missing key, the `TypeError` catches trying to index something that's not a `dict`.

If you expect this failure to be very common, this may not be ideal, as there's a bit of overhead for a `try .. except` block.

In that case you're stuck with what you have, although I'd write it as:

```
if 'key2' in d and d['key2'] and 'key3' in d['key2']:
    value = d['key2']['key3']
```

Or perhaps a bit more clearly:

```
if 'key2' in d and isinstance(d['key2'], dict) and 'key3' in d['key2']:
    value = d['key2']['key3']
```

If you're about to assign something else to `value` in the `else` part (like `None`), you could also consider:

```
value = d['key2']['key3'] if 'key2' in d and d['key2'] and 'key3' in d['key2'] else None
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I normally don't name variably by data type. I just tried to make a dumb example. Turned out to be really dumb :D

Comment: Also consider @AndrejKesely 's suggestion - using `.get()` is a nice and clean way to provide a safe default.

Comment: I eventually settled with the `Try-Catch` statement. I was looking for a clean way to do this, but if it works, why fix it?

Comment: That's fair enough - just keep in mind that if your code needs to be executed thousands or millions of times in rapid succession, there are solutions that may perform better.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `.get()` with default value:

```
val = d.get("key2", {}).get("key3", None)  # <-- you can put something else instead of `None`, this value will return if key2 or key3 doesn't exist
```

For example:

```
d = {"key1": "value1", "key2": {"key3": "value3"}}

val = d.get("key2", {}).get("key3", None)

if not val is None:
    print(val)
else:
    print("Not found.")
```